# File name changed on download

Tags: php, file-upload

i want to implement code so that when user will download that file, name of the file should be changed

as example

```
$uploaddir="files/userid/";
$filename=rand(1000,9999).time().rand(1000,9999);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);
```

suppose using this code file is uploaded it will be stored on server as name like this

23451232325654.pdf

but for user he/she will have logical name for it Like learn_php.php

when user want to download this file he/she will have this link to download

www.example.com/files/userid/23451232325654.pdf

but this file not stored on user's pc when downloaded as 23451232325654.pdf but i want to store it as their logical name as shown above
learn.php

Comment: Why you are uploading a file with different name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this no problem.  You just need a download script that will first send the correct header.  In this case, the header should be something like:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="learn_php.pdf"');
```

See example 1 in the [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

So instead of linking directly to the file (for example: http://website.com/content/129312.pdf), you would link to your download script (for example: http://website.com/download.php?file=129312.pdf).

And download would first send the headers, then the file contents.

**Obligatory note about security:** Using the filename directly from `$_GET` without sanitizing it opens up a huge security issue.  If you do it this way you NEED to sanitize it.

Comment: Thats probably true, but for me, most of the right side contains links about how to rename a file once its uploaded, here the OP wants to suggest a name at download time.  A small difference, but yes, I'm sure this has been answered here before :-)

Comment: i found this error when i open file..adobe reader could not open file because it is not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged(for example it is sent as email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded )

Comment: Two things, 1) post your code and 2) are you making sure that the file exists?  I've had this error when the header was sent but no data.  What is the size of the downloaded file?

Comment: code is same as your..but my file size is 5.2MB and download file shows 206bytes

Comment: 206 bytes indicates that the file isn't being sent.  Are you sure that `readfile(whatever)` can find `whatever`?  You should check the return value of readfile.